# Default form_params for guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Is there a way to globally add form_params to all requests with guzzle 6?

For example:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'global_form_params' => [ // This isn't a real parameter 
        'XDEBUG_SESSION_START' => '11845',
        'user_token' => '12345abc',
    ]
]);

$client->post('/some/web/api', [
    'form_params' => [
        'some_parameter' => 'some value'
    ]
]);
```

In my ideal world, the `post` would have the result of array_merge-ing `global_form_params` and `form_params`:

```
[
    'XDEBUG_SESSION_START' => '11845',
    'user_token' => '12345abc',
    'some_parameter' => 'some value',
]
```

I can see also wanting something like this for `query` or `json`

Answer (score 3):

According to [Creating a client](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-a-client) you can set "any number of default request options" and on the [GuzzleHttp\Client Source Code](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php)

```
$client = new Client['form_params' => [form values],]);
```

would apply your form_params to every request.

This could create issues with GET requests due to the `Content-Type` header being changed within [Client::applyOptions](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L282).  It would ultimately depend on server configuration.

If your intentions are to have the client make both GET and POST requests then you might be better served by moving the form_params into middleware. For example:

```
$stack->push(\GuzzleHttp\Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
    if ('POST' !== $request->getMethod()) {
        // pass the request on through the middleware stack as-is
        return $request;
    }

    // add the form-params to all post requests.
    return new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
        $request->getMethod(),
        $request->getUri(),
        $request->getHeaders() + ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($request->getBody() . '&' . http_build_query($default_params_array)),
        $request->getProtocolVersion()
    );  
});
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but I wanted to merge the "default" form_params with whatever is specified in each request.  I think my use of the word "default" is unclear, I will update my question.

Comment: modified to reflect the desired "merger"